# Devise invitable change accept_invitation_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

In the invitation mail I can see method that generates acceptation link:

```
accept_invitation_url(@resource, invitation_token: @token)
```

and I'd like to know how to edit(or override) this method so I can put there my custom route. I have seen some similar threads, but most of them are outdated or don't provide any working solutions.

Can someone explain me how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize mailer view with your own stuff

Use this for generate devise invitable views `rails generate devise_invitable:views` For more information about view check this [link](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#configuring-views).

And customize `app/views/devise/mailer/invitation_instruction.html.erb` to get your stuff working. In this file you can change this method to `<p><%= link_to 'Text Here', "YOUR_OWN_ROUTE_HERE?invitation_token=#{@token}" %></p>` by doing this you can send whatever link you like and then you have to write a route as well for it which calls the default method of devise.

**UPDATE**

When you invite user it will call create action of Users::InvitationsController and you can overide the controller also, refere [Customize devise invitable Controller](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#configuring-controllers)

Comment: It coul work, but i wanted not to change view but the function  or path itself

Comment: @Djozeph its better to override view. But if you stronly want to change helper you can redefine it in `router.rb` with `:as`  `post 'some/where', as: :accept_invitation`

Comment: I would agree with @itsnikolay as it's better to override rather than creating new functionality.

Comment: Ok I changed view, thanks for help!